# Scala 2.12: What is the equivalent of Java 8 method reference for universally quantified SAM trait?

Tags: java, scala, java-8, scala-2.12

My objective is to implement singleton value of algebraic data types (church-encoded) via the new scala 2.12 support of SAM (single abstract method) trait.

In Java, the following program return `true`:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Maybe<A> {

  <X> X fold(Supplier<X> empty, Function<A, X> just);

  static <A, X> X empty0(Supplier<X> empty, Function<A, X> just) {
    return empty.get();
  }

  static <A> Maybe<A> empty() {
      return Maybe::empty0;
  }

  static void main(String[] args) {
    Maybe<?> emptyString = Maybe.<String>empty();
    Maybe<?> emptyInt = Maybe.<Integer>empty();

    System.out.println(emptyString == emptyInt); // print "true".
  }
}
```

I tried to port this encoding to scala 2.12 but it does not compile:

```
@FunctionalInterface
trait Maybe[A] {
  def fold[X](empty: => X, just: A => X): X
}

object Maybe {
  def empty0[A, X](empty: => X, just: A => X): X = empty

  def empty[A]: Maybe[A] = empty0(_ ,_) // does not compile

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val emptyString: Maybe[String] = Maybe.empty
    val emptyInt: Maybe[Integer] = Maybe.empty

    print(emptyString eq emptyInt) // how to make this print "true"???
  }
}
```

The error I get is:
`missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2: <error>) => empty0(x$1, x$2))`

My objective is to get scalac trigger the same optimization done by Javac that make the java program print "true". I am open to whatever is necessary to satisfy scalac, as long as it does not use `asInstanceOf` nor `Nothing`/variance annotation.

**EDIT**: Since this is currently not supported, I opened a [feature request on the scala issue tracker](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9916) for this (please vote for it! ;-).

Comment: What happens if you replace the definition of empty with:
`def empty[A]: Maybe[A] = empty0`? Note that I don't have scala 2.12 installed and can't actually check if this is a valid response.

Comment: then I get `Error:(11, 33) polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type[...] missing argument list for method empty0 in object Maybe
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing "empty0 _" or "empty0(_,_)" instead of "empty0".
      def empty[A]: Maybe[A] =  empty0;`

Comment: You mean you're trying to get the compiler to wire this up for you instead of explicitly specifying where the arguments go?

Comment: I am just trying to get scalac trigger the same optimization done by Javac that mke the program print "true". I am open to whatever is necessary to satisfy scalac, as long as it does not use `asInstanceOf` or `Nothing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not allowed according to [the specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions):

> It follows that:
>
> - if class C defines a constructor, it must be accessible and must define exactly one, empty, argument list;
> - **m cannot be polymorphic**;
> - it must be possible to derive a fully-defined type U from S by inferring any unknown type parameters of C.

Comment: I see that a feature request on this was opened at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9916

Comment: yep, I opened it after I get answered by Alexey. Adding the link to question.